# my spi_interface code in Verilog is not working

Tags: verilog, spi

I have written a spi protocol in Verilog for communication between a master and a slave device. the problem that I am facing is I've written its testbench and in the simulation, as you all can see only the system clock is toggling and nothing else. my serial clock is not toggling, the data that I have provided in the testbench is not getting into the registers and is not showing in simulation and not even my slave select is changing. I dont understand what is the problem there were certain bugs that I have removed but it is still not working. can anyone just tell me how can I make this code work I will appreciate really it.

[image]

here is the link from where i took the information for spi. https://www.nxp.com/files-static/training_pdf/26821_68HC08_SPI_WBT.pdf

And here is the code. I have added detailed comments so that anyone who is reading could comprehend easily what is happening and i also added a testbench. Please review my code and I wii be thankful for your suggestions.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps



module spi_master(clk,sclk,miso,mosi,ss);

input clk,sclk;

output reg miso;

output reg mosi;

output reg ss;

reg [7:0] receive_register_slave; //slave receive data register

reg [7:0] shift_register_slave; //slave shift register

reg [7:0] data_in_slave; //slave data register that transfers data to system

reg [7:0] transmit_register; //data transmitting register

reg [7:0] shift_register; //data shift register

reg [7:0] receive_data_register; //receiver register

reg sptie; //interrupt signals for master

reg cpol ,cpha; //clock polarity and clock phase register

reg [7:0] data_in; //data comming from system

reg sprf; //interrupt which tells all 8 it data is transferred

reg sprie; //interrupt which indicate receive register is full

reg slave; //for declaring device as slave

reg master;  //for declaring device as master

parameter idle = 1'd0; //defining parameter for idle

//block to initialize the values

initial

begin

sptie = 1'd0; //interrupt to tell if transmit register is full or not

transmit_register = 8'd0; //initializing transmit register

shift_register = 8'd0; //initializing shift register

receive_data_register = 8'd0; //initializing receive data register

cpol = 1'd0; //initializing clock polarity to zero

cpha = 1'd0; //initializing clock phase to zero

ss = 1'd1; //initializing the slave select to one

sprf = 1'd0; //initializing the interrupt

sprie = 1'd0; //initializing the interrupt to zero

master = 1'd1;  //for a device to be a master it should be 1

slave = 1'd0;  //for a device to work as slave it should be 0

end

//initializing serial clock

assign sclk = clk/4;

//condition for assertion of ss

always@(*)

begin

 ss = (sclk == idle)?1'd1:1'd0;

end

//condition for assertion of master and slave control

always@(posedge sclk)

begin

if(shift_register <= mosi) master <= 1'b1;

else if (miso <= shift_register_slave) slave <= 1'b1;
end

//if interrupt is enabled data from system is written into transmit data register of master

always@(posedge sclk)

begin

if(sptie) transmit_register <= data_in;

else transmit_register <= 8'dz;

end

// if interrupt is not enabled data from transfer register is moved to shift regsiter

always@(posedge sclk)

begin

if(!sptie) shift_register <= transmit_register;

end

//if ss is low data from shift register is moved to output mosi

always@(posedge sclk)

begin

if(!ss) mosi <= shift_register;

end

//data comming into slave shift register and is from there transferred to system register

always@(posedge sclk)

begin

shift_register_slave <= mosi;

receive_register_slave <= shift_register_slave;

sprf = 1'b1;

sprie = 1'b1;

data_in_slave <= receive_register_slave;

sprf = 1'b0; //i made these bits low because currently i dont have a main program

sprie = 1'b0;

end

//shifting data out from slave shift register through miso line

always@(posedge sclk)

begin

if(!ss) miso <= shift_register_slave;

end

//receiving data frokm slave and transmitting data to system

always@(posedge sclk)

begin

if(!ss) shift_register <= miso;

receive_data_register <= shift_register;

data_in <= receive_data_register;

end

endmodule


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

this is the  test bench of the code

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module tb_spi_protocol();

reg clk,sclk;

wire mosi,miso,ss;

reg [7:0] receive_register_slave;

reg [7:0] shift_regsiter_slave;

reg [7:0] data_in_slave;

reg [7:0] transmit_register;

reg [7:0] shift_register;

reg [7:0] receiver_data_register;

reg [7:0] data_in;

reg sptie;

reg sprf;

reg sprie;

//instantiating the si_module in test bench

spi_master m1( .clk(clk),.sclk(sclk),.miso(miso),.mosi(mosi),.ss(ss));

//generating stimulus for testbench

initial

begin

clk = 25000000;

sclk = clk/4;

end

initial

begin

clk = 0;

sclk = 0;

forever #5 clk = ~clk;

forever #5 sclk = ~sclk;

end

initial

begin

#1 spi_master.sptie = 1'd1;

#2 @(posedge sclk) spi_master.data_in = 8'b10101010;

#2 spi_master.sptie = 1'b0;

#5 spi_master.sptie = 1'b1;

#3 @(posedge sclk) spi_master.data_in = 8'b00011110;

#2 spi_master.sptie = 1'b0;

$monitor ("time = %d,receive slave = %d,shift register = %d,data in slave = %d,receive data register = 
%d",$time,receive_register_slave,

shift_regsiter_slave,data_in_slave,receiver_data_register);

repeat (10) @(posedge sclk);

$stop;

$finish;

end

endmodule
```

Comment: This is where you learn basic debugging.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like a question already posted yesterday; please don't post the same problem multiple times, but rather *edit* the original to fix the issues pointed out.

Comment: `sclk` should be the *output* of an SPI master, not an input.  Focus on figuring out why your state machine isn't starting to perform any operations.  Perhaps you have an issue with whatever is supposed to start it.  It's not immediately clear what part of your design has the "agenda" of what is to be accomplished.

Comment: Chris Stratton,I edited but my answer wasn't got updated